# Android Java strange issue building URL

Tags: java, android, http

So I'm building an URL to be called to get a JSON response but facing a strange issue. Building the URL as shown below returns "Not found" but for testing purposes I just built the URL as such "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/person?api_key=XXX&query=brad" and didn't append anything and that returned the correct response. Also tried not encoding "text" and same thing...Not found. Any ideas?

```
        StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder();
        url.append("http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/person?api_key=XXX&query=").append(URLEncoder.encode(text, ENCODING));
        Log.v("URL", url.toString());
        try {
            HttpGet httpRequest = null;
            httpRequest = new HttpGet(url.toString());
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpRequest);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            BufferedHttpEntity bufHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
            InputStream input = bufHttpEntity.getContent();
            String result = toString(input);  

            //JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
            return result;
```

Comment: What does the line `Log.v("URL", url.toString());` print out?

Comment: It prints out the proper address which I even copy/pasted into browser and it worked...

Comment: Long shot, but is it possible that you need to encode your API key?

Comment: That didn't seem to do anything ^^

Comment: Not sure what's going on because now it's not working the way it previously was even though it works fine in the browser =\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the code I have below. I've copied and pasted it out of some code I use and I know it works. May not solve your problem but I think its worth a shot. I've edited it a little bit and it should just be copy and paste into your code now.

```
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(new URI(url.toString()));
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (String line = null; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
        builder.append(line).append("\n");
    }
    JSONObject jResponse = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
```